# GPUImage examples not working

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpuimage

I've hit a roadblock with using `GPUImage`.  I'm trying to apply a filter (SepiaFilter or OpacityFilter) on a prerecorded video.  What I'm expecting to see is the video played back with the filter applied to it.   I followed the `SimpleFileVideoFilter` example for my code.  What I ended up with is a video that is unplayable by Quicktime (m4v extension) and the live preview of the rendering all skewed.  I thought it was my code at first so I ran the example app from the examples directory and lo and behold I got the same issue.  Is the library broken?  I just refreshed from master out of `GitHub`.

Thanks!

Here's a sample output of the video generated
http://youtu.be/SDb9GfVf9Lc

No matter what filter is applied the resultant video are all similar. (all skewed )

@Brad Larson (I hope you see this message), do you know what I can be doing wrong?  I am using the latest XCode and source code of GPUImage.  I also tried using the latest from CocoaPods as well. Both end up the same.

Comment: To add, I am using the latest XCode and target the builds against iOS7.  Is GPUImage not compatible with the latest iOS release?
@BradLarson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to run this example via the Simulator. Movie playback in the Simulator [has been broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19986910/19679) for as long as I can remember. You need to run this on an actual device to get movie playback to work.

Unfortunately, one of the recent pull requests that I brought in appears to have introduced some crashing bugs even there, and I may need to revert those changes and figure out what went wrong. Even that's not an iOS version thing, it's a particular bug with a recent code addition. I haven't had the time to dig into it and fix it, though.

Comment: Thanks Brad.  I eventually figured it was due to running on the simulator and not the device.  :(  I just haven't logged in to update my question.  I actually was about to remove it for being such a bone head question.  It just didn't occur to me that it only worked on the device right away.  I figured that might be the case for some of the advanced filters/features.  I didn't think it was true for all the examples.

I've managed to pick up the iPhone 3D book and an openGL 3.0 reference book (may trade it in for 2.0) so hopefully I'll be able to make progress much faster now.

Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelNguyen - The thing is, it should work in the Simulator, just never has. I can't quite figure out why that is. It's quite odd.